# Do we need a "flashing"/"installing-touch" tag?

Tags: discussion

As the source for Ubuntu Touch has been released, a lot of people are trying to flash their Nexus 7 with it. A lot of problems may happen here, and many more generic questions related to installing this Ubuntu edition may appear. There is already a [significant](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=ubuntu%20touch) [rise](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=nexus%207) in such questions, and of course many more are about to be expected (Consider: How do I install Ubuntu Touch on X device? How to solve common Y problem when flashing Z with Ubuntu Touch?).

I believe this kind of questions deserves a common tag. It might be "installation", but that's generally not favorable, because installation on mobile devices differs significantly from desktop machines.

Possible solutions I came up with include:

1. Using a [flashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/flashing) tag, to distinguish from [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation). Or, alternatively, a variation like [installation-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation-touch).
2. Sticking to the [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) tag.
3. Preferring the [touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/touch) tag for both flashing and using Ubuntu Touch.
4. Not using a common tag for these questions at all.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

Folksonomical systems (tagging) are *supposed* to work so that you apply situational labels to things in a way that you can cross-reference with other things that also share a list of tags in order to find similarities. The more tags in common, the more similar.

In that vein, I'd be opting for either #2 or #3. **Combining** the following:

- [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch) because that's the OS,
- [nexus7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nexus7) (or other device tag) to explain what hardware you're running on, and
- [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) to explain what you're doing.

That should put anybody reading the question in a position where they can quickly understand what the question is asking just by looking at the tags.

This also allows people to search for questions based on these tags so they can find questions about installing Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7s... serving the folksonomical purpose.

Answer (score -6):

What about a more categorical name like:

- `touch-installation` <-- This is the one I would go with.
- `tablet-installation`
- `phone-installation`

Since flashing can also mean flashing as in BIOS, Firmware updates on Desktops/Laptops, it could also be added `touch-flashing` or similar.